# Proof about symmetry in isometries.

Tags: proof-writing, euclidean-geometry

Suppose $f: \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$ is an isometry of the reals.
 Prove that $f$ is a symmetry about a point if and only if $f$ has a unique fixed point.

**Part 1**: The assumption is $f$ is a symmetry and we want to conclude it has a unique fixed point.

**Part 2**: The assumption is $f$ is an isometry with a unique fixed point and we want to conclude $f$ is a symmetry.

Definition: A fixed point of $f$ is $x$ such that 
$f(x)=x$.

I'm not sure the best way to approach this problem, I think for both parts a proof by contradiction would be easiest, however I am not sure how do either of these.

Answer (score 0):

For part $1$, use the fact that a symmetry is a mirroring of $\mathbb R$ in a point, so that point must be fixed.
For part $2$, show that the isometry is not a translation. Then, deduce that is must be a symmetry.

Comment: I have got part 2 figured out, thanks for the hint.  Part 1 I am still confused, how do you mean to use that a symmetry is a mirroring of $\mathbb R$ ?

Comment: A symmetry sends x to a+(a-x) for some real number a, and a is fixed.